# Syntax Highlighting for Scintilla in C++

Tags: c++, mfc, scintilla

I'm working on MFC based code editor. The part on which I'm stuck is when i need to add color to keywords, basically nothing happens. `SCE_C_WORD` should be setting it up (I also found `SCE_C_WORD2`, but also nothing happens).

```
void ScintillaCtrl::SetUpEditor()
{
    SendEditor(SCI_SETKEYWORDS, NULL, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(ini.GetKeywords()));

    SetAStyle(SCE_C_COMMENT, ini.GetColor(_T("comment")));
    SetAStyle(SCE_C_COMMENTLINE, ini.GetColor(_T("comment")));
    SetAStyle(SCE_C_COMMENTDOC, ini.GetColor(_T("comment")));
    SetAStyle(SCE_C_NUMBER, ini.GetColor(_T("number")));
    SetAStyle(SCE_C_STRING, ini.GetColor(_T("string")));
    SetAStyle(SCE_C_CHARACTER, ini.GetColor(_T("string")));
    SetAStyle(SCE_C_UUID, ini.GetColor(_T("uuid")));
    SetAStyle(SCE_C_OPERATOR, ini.GetColor(_T("operators")));
    SetAStyle(SCE_C_PREPROCESSOR, ini.GetColor(_T("preprocessor")));
    SetAStyle(SCE_C_WORD, ini.GetColor(_T("keywords")));
    //SetAStyle(SCE_C_WORD2, ini.GetColor(_T("keywords")));
}
```

This is method where I'm setting up editor for language (reading colors from ini files). I already checked and color is written in ini file and all other colors work (comments, operators, etc).

Edit: Code for tab width, lexer, etc...

```
void ScintillaCtrl::LoadDefaultState()
{
    SendEditor(SCI_SETLEXER, SCLEX_NULL);
    SendEditor(SCI_SETTABWIDTH,4);
    SetAStyle(STYLE_DEFAULT, RGB(0, 0, 0), RGB(255, 255, 255), 10, "Arial");
    SendEditor(SCI_SETCARETFORE, RGB(0, 0, 0));
    SendEditor(SCI_STYLECLEARALL, NULL);
    SendEditor(SCI_SETSELBACK, TRUE, ini.GetColor(_T("selection")));
}
```

Comment: I suggest to check examples like this: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/14722/building-a-simple-c-script-compiler-from-scintilla

Comment: That is example i have been working by

Comment: The example makes a few more calls, did you try this too? Maybe you are missing something.

Comment: I have those calls in another method since they are the same for each language so they aren't here, im gonna edit my post and put that code here now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve it. Problem was that i was sending keywords in wide char (unicode) to Scintilla, but it only accepts them in char, so when i changed it to char it worked.